# cs50 week 2 lab 2; not consistently printing out correct winner or "tie"

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement, char, cs50

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};

int compute_score(string word);

int main(void)
{
    // Get input words from both players
    string word1 = get_string("Player 1: ");
    string word2 = get_string("Player 2: ");

    // Score both words
    int score1 = compute_score(word1);
    int score2 = compute_score(word2);

    if (score1 > score2)
    {
        printf("Player 1 Wins!\n");
    }
    if (score1 < score2)
    {
        printf("Player 2 Wins!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Tie!\n");
    }
}

int compute_score(string word)
{
    int score = 0;
    int n = strlen(word);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
       //if letter is uppercase
       if (isupper (word[i]))
       {
            POINTS[i] = word[i] - 65;
            score += POINTS[i];
       }
       //if letter is lowercase
       if (islower(word[i]))
       {
            POINTS[i] = word[i] - 97;
            score += POINTS[i];
       }
        //if character is not a letter
       else
       {
            i += 1;
       }
    }
     return score;
}
```

//For example, when I type "Oh," for player one in command line to test; and "oh," for player two- it prints "player two wins!" (it's suppose to be a tie). When I switch, it prints bother "player 1 wins!" and "tie!" I'm at my wits end on how to  solve the issue. unfortunately my debugging isn't loading properly to my computer as I was trying to practice going through and figuring it out. Any direction would be appreciated.

This is my second week trying to understand programming, I knew it'd be rough, I wasn't ready for this steep a ride!

Comment: `i += 1;` - remove this. `i` is incremented anyway by the `for` loop..

Comment: Also replace `if (islower(word[i]))` with `else if (islower(word[i]))`, otherwise the last `else` will fire for uppercase letters. Or remove that `else` altogether with the aforementioned `i` increment.

Comment: Same broken logic  in the `if/else` construct in `main`. The first `if` is disconnected from the second `if/else`. make it `else if`.

Comment: Why are you overwriting the `POINTS` array? Did you mean `score += POINTS[ word[i] - 'A' ];` ? Or in two simpler lines like you have, `int index = word[i] - 'A'; score += POINTS[index];`

Comment: You should write `'A'` and `'a'` instead of 65 and 97; it makes it clearer what you are doing.

Comment: Rather than special casing upper and lowercase, just convert the character to lower case.  Something like: `int compute_score(const char *word) { int score = 0; while( *word ) { if( isalpha(*word) ){ score += POINTS[tolower(*word - 'a')]; } word += 1; } return score; }`

Answer (score 1):

Within the function `compute_score` you are changing the array `POINTS`

```
        POINTS[i] = word[i] - 65;
        POINTS[i] = word[i] - 97;
```

So it would be better if the array would be declared with the qualifier `const`

```
// Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
const int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
```

And there is no great sense to declare it as global.
Move the array declaration in the function `compute_score`.

Also you are incorrectly using the index `i`

```
        score += POINTS[i];
```

And this else statement

```
   else
   {
        i += 1;
   }
```

is redundant and wrong.

The function can look the following way

```
int compute_score( string word )
{
    // Points assigned to each letter of the alphabet
    static const int POINTS[] = {1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 1, 8, 5, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 10};
    const size_t N = sizeof( POINTS ) / sizeof( *POINTS );

    int score = 0;

    for ( ; *word; ++word )
    {
       //if letter is uppercase
       if ( isupper( ( unsigned char )*word ) )
       {
            size_t i = *word - 'A';

            if ( i < N ) score += POINTS[i];
       }
       //if letter is lowercase
       else if ( islower( ( unsigned char )*word ) )
       {
            size_t i = *word - 'a';

            if ( i < N ) score += POINTS[i];
       }
    }

    return score;
}
```

Also in main you have to write

```
if (score1 > score2)
{
    printf("Player 1 Wins!\n");
}
else if (score1 < score2)
{
    printf("Player 2 Wins!\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Tie!\n");
}
```

Comment: Maybe this answer would be more appropriate without using pointers; revert to array notation in 'comput_score'... This is a "week 2" assignment, and pointers haven't yet been mentioned in the course. Otherwise, good answer! :-)